# Is the framework within the framework a problem?

Tags: ios, cocoa, frameworks, app-store

I used pods in the Cocoa framework.

Is there a problem when you include this project in your main project and upload it to the App Store? What is the reason for rejection?

```
pod 'SnapKit'
pod 'GzipSwift'
pod 'RealmSwift'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an app in appstore which includes a framework and that framework includes many frameworks in it and it's approved by apple.

I think in your case , you might be using a framework which tries to access Private APIs of iOS.

Hope this helps.

Include apple's rejection message to give you more insights.